# grails 3.3 detachedcriteria appears to give incorrect result

Tags: grails, detachedcriteria

I have a self-referencing Grails 3.3.5 domain class of the form (simplified version)

```
class Animal {
    String name
    String dateOfBirth
    Animal sire
    Animal dam
}
```

I am using DetachedCriteria to build up a back-end query controlled by a JQuery tables .gsp front end that shows columns

```
name
dateOfBirth
sire.name
dam.name
dam.sire.name
```

and provides column filters on each column.

This all seems to be working as hoped-for except for one case: if I combine a filter value for sire.name and dam.sire.name no results are returned, ever (nor any error message or any other sign of distress).

The two related criterial builders look like this:

```
criteria = criteria.build {
    sire {
        ilike 'name', "%${v.search.value}%"
    }
}
```

and

```
criteria = criteria.build {
    dam {
        sire {
            ilike 'name', "%${v.search.value}%"
        }
    }
}
```

Just to be clear, filtering on dam.name and dam.sire.name works as expected, as does on name and dam.sire.name, sire.name and dam.name and so forth.

I am guessing that there is some interaction between the two joins to "sire", one inside the "dam" join.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand the description above but if `DetachedCriteria` are yielding incorrect results, please file a bug report at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues and link to a sample app which demonstrates the problem and we will straighten it out.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I will work on that right away.

Comment: I'm going to file the bug report, but just for some closure here, I've found a very ugly workaround - if the detached criteria for dam/sire/name PRECEEDS that for sire/name, the criteria returns expected results; if the order is the other way around, the criteria returns no results.

Comment: The issue #1089 is now filed on GitHub.